# Struggling to view all database entries in my HTML output

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, ruby

I've got a pretty simple Ruby on Rails app that has a text box where I can enter content, limited to 200 characters, into a database.

My goal is to list the items below the text box so that when a user enters something, it appears at the top of an ever-growing list.

Right now I have some crappy code that doesn't work, but I'm not sure why.

In my view page, located at `home.html.erb`, I have this area for the lessons to be viewed in:

```
<td class="my-lessons">

</td>
```

In my `Lesson controller` I have the following:

```
  def printLesson
    @lesson = Lesson.find(params[:id])

    puts @lesson.content
  end
```

I'm not sure how to call printLesson in my code and just generally how to show the content of the Lessons database.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: It seems you are not using RESTful routing, am I right?

Comment: I believe I am. I'm not advanced enough to do anything else right now. I'm not calling the method properly, I know that. I'm not sure how to call that method and have it spit out the contents of the first Lesson

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`home.html.erb` gets rendered when you go to `http://localhost:3000/lesson/home` provided you have the appropriate route defined in `routes.rb`:

```
match 'lesson/home' => 'lesson#home'
```

So in your `Lesson` controller, in the `home` action have the following:

```
def home
  @lessons = Lesson.all
end
```

Now in your `home.html.erb` view render the contents of `@lessons`

```
<% @lessons.each do |lesson| %>
<tr>
    <td class="my-lessons">
      <%= lesson.Name %>
    </td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

The problem you're having is thinking that you have to tell Rails to spit out the input in your controller action (the line `puts @lesson.content`). Rails works on convention. Any instance variables created in your controller's action will be accessible in your view. So the `@lessons` variable in the example above is accessible in the `home.html.erb` view.

I suggest having a read at the following for more info to do with routes and rendering views:

- [http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: One miscommunication I think that came from my end, the route to home.html.erb is app/views/pages/home.html.erb rather than app/views/lessons/home.html.erb. Any idea what kind of routing finagling needs to be done?

Comment: The location of the views in the app don't correspond to paths in the URL. You're far better of following Rails conventions and putting it in `app/views/lesson/home.html.erb`.

Comment: Thanks Soliah. So I've got that working, showing those lessons. What's the most efficient way to get those same things showing up in views/pages/home.html.erb?

Comment: The easiest for you would be to move the code from the `lesson_controller.rb` to a new controller `page_controller.rb`, renaming instances of `Lesson` to `Page`. Then modify the route to go to `pages` instead.